# Allow docker container to accept traffic from public IPs

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, postgresql-9.4

My docker container running on AWS EC2 is configured to allow traffic from only `172.17.0.0:5432`. I'd like to change this to allow traffic from public IP addresses? Do I use `0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp`?

How do I change this configuration? I'm ssh'd into aws ec2.

Context, I am running postgres on docker container / image in aws ec2. However, my connection request fails as the traffic is blocked from remote machines.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
                        host="204.xxx.xxx.xxx",
                        port="5432",
                        database="name_db",
                        user="postgres",
                        password="xxxxxxxxxx"
       )


OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "204.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: how do you run your container? did you try `telnet` from the remote machine? (to ensure that's not a firewall)

Comment: container is running on aws ec2. when I attempt to `Telnet` to ec2 instance public IP, I get `Unable to connect to remote host`

Comment: its not the docker container that's blocking your request its the postgres config, you need to modify your postgres config to allow internet connection

Answer (score 0):

have you created the appropriate rules for the AWS server that hosts the docker container?

Comment: Yes, I setup rules to allow inbound traffic for AWS server.

Comment: have you tried to check the configuration of Postgres?